# angularjs profile image upload is getting changed only on empty cache and hard reload

Tags: angularjs, image, caching, image-processing, browser-cache

in my angularjs app.. trying to **reupload an profile image**.. image is getting uploaded successfully but bcoz of cache problem it is showing previous uploaded image only..
for that i have tried..

> $templateCache.removeAll();
>
> $state.reload();
>
> $window.location.reload();

even i m **appending current timestamp** after the image url 
its not working

if m using **$timeout** then my problem is solved but that is not good user experience..

I need some better solution for that.. help me out

even in headers we are using

> **cache-control: no-cache**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem by appending some random string to image url itself (not after image url) on every new upload.. you can append current timestamp also..

for me current timestamp was creating problem bcoz it was creating inconsistency while image processing.